# How to call main class in Netbeans Java

Tags: java

Sir, this is my first post in this forum.
I am using Netbeans 12 and trying to create java maven project.

I have this main class

```
package com.mycompany.crud;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static com.mycompany.crud.set_connection.connect;

/**
 *
 * @author zanib
 */
public class main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     *
     * @throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        connect();
    }
}
```

and this is connect class

```
package com.mycompany.crud;
import java.sql.*;
/**
 *
 * @author zanib
 */
public class set_connection {

    public static Connection connect() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        Connection con = null;

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1; databaseName=at20; user=sa; password=123";
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
            System.out.println("Connection is successful");
          } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

When I run main class then I get this message
Connection is successful

I means database is connected

Now I have a jFrame Form that has a jButton1, from that button I want to connect database for crud operation.
In other words how to call connection() in jFrame form?

Please help[image]

Comment: You can call it in exactly the same way you are calling it from main()

Comment: java is `CamelCase`, not `snake_case`.

Comment: Sir I created a new jFrame Form and it has these codes

```
package com.mycompany.crud;

import static com.mycompany.crud.set_connection.connect;

public class frm_test extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public frm_test() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
     public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        connect();
    }
```
when I run form it says
com/mycompany/crud/frm_test.java:[76,24] method main(java.lang.String[]) is already defined in class com.mycompany.crud.frm_test